# Installing Marathon on apache mesos

Tags: docker, apache-flink, mesos, marathon

I want to set Flink cluster via apache mesos. I have three physical nodes with docker installed on them. Each docker has an installed ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I installed apache mesos on the docker using this link without any problem:

[Apache Mesos-building](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/building/)

In the Flink website, I understood Marathon should be installed on Mesos to provide High availability. I could not install marathon. Then, I provided a docker with a fresh ubuntu 16.04 desktop on it and tried to follow this instruction to install Mesos and Marathon:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E56151BF

ISTRO=$(lsb_release -is | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

CODENAME=$(lsb_release -cs)

echo "deb http://repos.mesosphere.io/${DISTRO} ${CODENAME} main"| sudo 
tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mesosphere.list

sudo apt-get update
```

I did not get any error in running above commands;but I got this error while I was running the command:

```
sudo apt-get -y install mesos
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package mesos

Would you please tell me how I can install marathon on Mesos in cluster of three different nodes? Do I have to install mesos on ubuntu server in one of these platforms like "AWS, Azure" instead of installing Mesos on three physical nodes with Ubuntu Desktop?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you install zookeeper for your cluster ?
if yes you can install marathon , running this

```html
curl -O http://downloads.mesosphere.com/marathon/v1.5.1/marathon-1.5.1.tgz
tar xzf marathon-1.5.1.tgz
./bin/start --master zk://zk1.foo.bar:2181,zk2.foo.bar:2181/mesos --zk zk://zk1.foo.bar:2181,zk2.foo.bar:2181/marathon
```

you can follow this link https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/

Comment: I have installed marathon on ubuntu 18.10 without any error. Also I installed Zookeeper. In /$MARATHON_HOME/bin, there is no "start" file. I ran "marathon" with "/$MARATHON_HOME/bin/marathon" and got "connection refused". Would you please tell me it is right?

Comment: would you please see this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723911/warn-session-0x0-for-server-null-unexpected-error-closing-socket-connection-an]? Thanks.